# HardFault during erasing Flash in debug mode

Tags: arm, embedded, bootloader, firmware, flash-memory

I've written a custom bootloader using C to run on ARM cortex_M4 but I had a HardFault exception when using the debug mode. This exception appears just in debug mode, when I use release mode everithing works.

I've checked that the Flash/Erase code is loaded to RAM before the execution of erase command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ARM Cortex-M4 only refers to the ARM core; it does not define any the flash memory controller.  You should specify the MCU/SoC you are using.  Without exposition of the the code or more debugging information it is not possible to answer, but if I had to guess, is it possible you have interrupt service routines in Flash and interrupts are not disabled during erase/programming?  Either disable interrupts or if you need interrupts, use RAM resident ISRs and move the vector table.

Comment: did you compare the code between release and debug,  what debugging did you do to find where the fault happens?

Comment: Most likely a data refernce that gets optimed out.  Interrupts are another possibility, but i think debug/release would only change frequency.